# Count number of commas using xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to write an xpath expression to count the number of commas in an element. Is it possible to do that? If yes, then could someone help me with the expression. I need to count the commas from the  node.

```
<SOISWPUpload>
  <User>admin</User>
  <SWPIdentifiers>,,,,,U,,,SWP,20120630,,,,4113,,COAC,TLMCOAC
,,,,,U,,,SWP,20120630,,,,4113,,COAC,TLMCOAC</SWPIdentifiers>
</SOISWPUpload>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
string-length() - string-length(translate(., ',', '')
```

In this concrete case you may want to specify the context-node:

```
string-length(/*/SWPIdentifiers) - string-length(translate(/*/SWPIdentifiers, ',', '')
```

Comment: @user1567386: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Could you, please, *accept* the answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to it)?